# React Router Dom v6.4 doesn't allow history.listen (prior suggestions deprecated) with createBrowserRouter or createMemoryRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

react-router-dom v. 6.4.2 doesn't allow history.listen as referenced in the code example below.  This is for a mfe with module federation.

In the code example using history.listen, if a link is clicked in the remote (loaded as mfe) then the memory history (memory router now) current path will be updated.  It will then call onNavigate to tell the host container which is using browser history (browser router now) that the current path has changed.

Prior suggestions were to use UNSAFE_NavigationContext, useHistory, unstable_HistoryRouter, import {...} from 'history', etc.  Apparently, those prior methods were temporary migration aids from v5 to v6.3 and with v6.4+ are now deprecated in favor of the new data api's in 6.4. See [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0-pre.14/routers/history-router)

> we do not intend to support custom histories moving forward. This API
> is here as a migration aid. We recommend removing custom histories
> from your app.

Additionally, [from the maintainers of RRD](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router):

> We recommend updating your app to use one of the new routers from 6.4.

After searching here and within both open and closed issues on [remix-RRD](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8264) I have been unable to find a workable solution based on the above for replacing history.listen, .push or .location with the new data api's (routers) using createBrowserRouter or createMemoryRouter as referenced [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#picking-a-router)

There are many open issues on the react-router-dom page relating to [this use case](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9422).

Original marketing/src/bootstrap.tsx from remote

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { createMemoryHistory, createBrowserHistory } from 'history' <= Not Supported
import App from './App'

let root: { render: (arg0: JSX.Element) => void } | null = null

// Mount function to start up the app
const mount = (el: any, { onNavigate, defaultHistory, initialPath }: any) => {
  if (!el) {
    root = null
    return
  }
  // If defaultHistory in development and isolation use BrowserHistory
  const history =
    defaultHistory ||
    // Otherwise use MemoryHistory and initial path from container
    createMemoryHistory({
      initialEntries: [initialPath],
    })

  if (onNavigate) {
    history.listen(onNavigate)                  <= Not Supported
  }

  root = root ? root : createRoot(el)

  root.render(<App history={history} />)

  return {
    onParentNavigate({ pathname: nextPathname }: any) {
      const { pathname } = history.location      <= Not Supported

      if (pathname !== nextPathname) {
        history.push(nextPathname)               <= Not Supported
      }
    },
  }
}

// If we are in development and in isolation,
// call mount immediately
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devRoot = document.querySelector('#_marketing-dev-root')

  if (devRoot) {
    mount(devRoot, { defaultHistory: createBrowserHistory() })
  }
}

// We are running through container
// and we should export the mount function
export { mount }
```

Replacement marketing/src/bootstrap.tsx from remote (in progress)

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createMemoryRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './App'

import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage'

import Landing from './components/Landing'
import Pricing from './components/Pricing'

let root: { render: (arg0: JSX.Element) => void } | null = null

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Landing />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: 'pricing',
        element: <Pricing />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]

// Mount function to start up the app
const mount = (
  el: Element,
  {
    onNavigate,
    defaultRouter,
  }: {
    onNavigate: (() => void) | null
    defaultRouter: any
  },
): unknown => {
  if (!el) {
    root = null
    return
  }
  // if in development and isolation, use browser router. If not, use memory router
  const router = defaultRouter || createMemoryRouter(routes)

  if (onNavigate) {
    router.listen(onNavigate) // There is no history.listen anymore.  router.listen is not a function
  }

  root = root ? root : createRoot(el)
  
  root.render(<App router={router} />)
}

// If we are in development and in isolation,
// call mount immediately
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devRoot = document.querySelector('#_marketing-dev-root')

  if (devRoot) {
    mount(devRoot, { defaultRouter: createBrowserRouter(routes) })
    console.log('defaultRouter')
  }
}

// We are running through container
// and we should export the mount function
export { mount }
```

Original marketing/src/App.tsx from remote

```
import './MuiClassNameSetup'
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Landing from './components/Landing'
import Pricing from './components/Pricing'

export default function _({ history }: any) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />
          <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Replacement marketing/src/App.tsx from remote (in progress)

```
import './MuiClassNameSetup'
import React from 'react'
import {
  RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function App({ router }: any) {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}
```

Original container/src/components/MarketingApp.tsx from host

```
import { mount } from 'marketing/MarketingApp'
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'   <= Not Supported

export default function _() {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const history = useHistory()                  <= Not Supported

  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      initialPath: history.location.pathname,
      onNavigate: ({ pathname: nextPathname }: any) => {
        const { pathname } = history.location   <= Not Supported

        if (pathname !== nextPathname) {
          history.push(nextPathname)            <= Not Supported
        }
      },
    })

    history.listen(onParentNavigate)            <= Not Supported
  }, [history])

  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

Replacement container/src/components/MarketingApp.tsx from host (in progress)

```
import { mount } from 'marketing/MarketingApp'
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function _() {
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    mount(ref.current, {
      onNavigate: () => {
        console.log('The container noticed navigation in Marketing')
      },
    })
  })

  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

Looking for a solution to replace history.listen, history.location and history.push that works with the new v6.4 data api's?

Comment: This is what happens when a classic piece of open source is quietly shifted to serve a for-profit organization.

Comment: Per one of the maintainers of react-router-dom it is because of the new Navigation API for modern client-side routing for single-page-applications. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/navigation-api/

Comment: Yes – just like axios could have dropped XHR requests for fetch, but introducing unwanted changes on a core SPA library is questionable at best. This is how it should be handled: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1219. I digress!

Comment: `history.push` was replaced by the `navigate` function via the `useNavigate` hook, `location` is accessed via the `useLocation` hook, and `history.listen` doesn't exist now. What do you need from the `listen` function, the `action` and `location`?

Comment: Maybe both? In the host “Container” I have a callback function `onNavigate`.  That callback function is received by the remote “Marketing”.  When navigation occurs in the remote “Marketing” I need to call `onNavigate` inside the remote.

The remote is using `createMemoryBrowser()` and when the path changes I need to call the `onNavigate` function and print the `console.log` statement shown in line 10 of `Replacement container/src/components/MarketingApp.tsx from host (in progress)`.  The host “Container” is using `createBrowserRouter`.  Both host and remote are using the new data routers.

Comment: So you just need to know when the route changes?

Comment: Yes! Within the `mount` function in bootstrap.tsx.

Comment: @Optionwiz did you find the fix for this router update? if so could u please share the repo link. I am too struggling with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the maintainers of RRD just posted a [new implementation detail to replace history.listen](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9422#issuecomment-1301182219) which is for v6.4+. See `router.subscribe()` below.

```
let router = createBrowserRouter(...);

// If you need to navigate externally, instead of history.push you can do:
router.navigate('/path');

// And instead of history.replace you can do:
router.navigate('/path', { replace: true });

// And instead of history.listen you can:
router.subscribe((state) => console.log('new state', state));
```

Unfortunately, the new implementation is also unstable and is considered a beta test implementation.

> Now, for the bad news  . Just like unstable_HistoryRouter we also
> consider this type of external navigation and subscribing to be
> unstable, which is why we haven't documented this and why we've marked
> all the router APIs as @internal PRIVATE - DO NOT USE in
> JSDoc/Typescript. This isn't to say that they'll forever be unstable,
> but since it's not the normally expected usage of the router, we're
> still making sure that this type of external-navigation doesn't
> introduce problems (and we're fairly confident it doesn't with the
> introduction of useSyncExternalStore in react 18!)
>
> If this type of navigation is necessary for your app and you need a
> replacement for unstable_HistoryRouter when using RouterProvider then
> we encourage you use the router.navigate and router.subscribe methods
> and help us beta test the approach! Please feel free to open new GH
> issues if you run into any using that approach and we'll use them to
> help us make the call on moving that towards future stable release.

Comment: Oh boy, it'd sure be nice if the RRD maintainers were a little more open/up front about what I'd consider pretty major breaking changes. They are fundamentally changing behaviors devs have come to rely on. Sure they say they are "unstable" and are internal implementation details... but clearly the use case is there otherwise so many of us wouldn't be left scrambling to figure out how to replicate behavior we've grown accustomed to using.

Comment: This upgrade to v6 is such a headache

Comment: Seems like you still have to give up too much with v6.  Had to temporarily put a MFE project on hold due to the new v6 introduced UX issues.